# How do I automate tab selection on a website

Tags: tabs, web, selection

Here is the website I am trying to access. I dont want the default tab (Day) though, I want to select the Season tab

https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/futures/uk-financial-futures#!/2017/05/23

The link appears to be exactly the same whichever tab is chose making differentiation impossible as far as I can tell.

Any help on this would be much appreciated, using whichever programming method and language is appropriate.

Kind Regards

Barry Walsh

Answer (score 0):

The URL does not change since this is an ajax request, which you can see from MarketDataTableAController's getPageData function. You can read about them here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Ive inspected your html and you seem to be using angular. On further inpection you can see that the tabs have ng-click="setActiveTab(tab)" attribute on them. So whenever user clicks, this function gets executed. It is a matter of using this function with the appropriate tab object to get the content to change. You for example could put setActiveTab(tab) into your controller init method since setActiveTab() calls the forementioned getPageData() function to update the page.

Also the tab you are looking for is page.tabs[5] ($parent.page.tabs[5] if referring from TabController) since this is the tab with the label of season. Pass that to setActiveTab() and it should show you the season instead.

**However this might not be a good solution since the tab array ordering might change**. Then you would need to loop over all objects in page.tabs and see if tab.label === "Season" and pass that in the function instead or better yet use the $filter service provided by angular which would look more cleaner.

Your code source also seems to be minimized and its not very easy to read.